# How can I toggle between states of a button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for the icons for connect and disconnect.
I want the application to swap between these two icons onClick.
I'm new to React, but haven't any helpful resources yet. 
Here's the code as it is so far:

```
 { user.connected ? 
    (
    <Button color="info" simple size="sm">
      <PersonAddDisabled className={classes.footerIcons} /> Disconnect
    </Button> 
    )
    : 
    (
     <Button color="info" size="sm">
        <PersonAdd className={classes.footerIcons} /> Connect
     </Button> 
    )
}
```

As it is above, I am address whether they are connected or not, but I'm not sure how to implement a toggle of those two buttons, where onClick it will switch between the two.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

here is a code 
Your state

```
 state = {
    connected: true
 }

 onClickButton(){      
   this.setState(prevState => {connected: !this.prevState.connected}) 
 }
```

Your code

```
{ this.state.connected ? 
  (
  <Button color="info" simple size="sm" onClick={ this.onClickButton }>
   <PersonAddDisabled className={ classes.footerIcons } /> Disconnect
  </Button> 
  )
  : 
  (
  <Button color="info" size="sm" onClick={ this.onClickButton }>
    <PersonAdd className={ classes.footerIcons } /> Connect
  </Button> 
  )
}
```